# Notepad Automatically Launches Upon Boot Up of my Windows 7 64-Bit Desktop PC

Tags: windows-7, boot, notepad, attributes

Around 12 months ago, when my Windows 7 PC boots, Notepad started to appear automatically on the desktop (as a duplicate i.e. one on top of the other), both displaying the same writing inside, and the name of the Notepad was: desktop-Notepad.

```
[.ShellClassInfo]
LocalizedResourceName=@%SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll,-21787
```

I can't remember the exact details as it's been so long now, but a friend told me this was due to a "hidden attribute" belonging to Notepad becoming "unhidden"and therefore allowing Notepad to show itself on the desktop at startup. He showed me a series of steps to either hide the attribute again or to delete it (telling me that upon restart of my computer it would be recreated/regenerated.)

I did indeed follow his guidance however after trying to hide it or delete the attribute (it was never recreated after restart which supposedly it should have done).

One Notepad still is autolaunched with the text as shown above every time I startup my PC. As I found this forum I thought I might try again for a solution to prevent Notepad from launching.

Comment: This is the classic signed that you are or were infected with Malware.

Comment: @Ramhound - No I dont believe that to be the case. What I was told 12 months ago, by my friend is that Microsoft has admitted there to be a bug in the Windows OS that also shows itself in Windows 7 - this concurs with the answers given by Paul and Dave below

Comment: @Simon, what malware removal program have you used though to rule this out? Many bugs / errors that occur can be similar to other bugs / errors - so although it looks like one thing (a MS bug) it doesn't mean it IS a MS bug, so let's rule it out; Malwarebytes should suffice.

Comment: @DaveRook at the time I was using Avast Pro, Private Firewall in addition to Malwarebytes Antimalware, Spyware Blaster & Dr Web On Demand Scanner. The only difference is now I have been using NIS for the past 3 months I guess in stead of Avast Pro. I have always been conscious of running regular scans. Yes MBAM is an excellent program which I probably run at least once a week if not more

Comment: @Ramhound - My apologies Ramhound, yes it could well have been a virus, I was a bit blunt with you. Since I have a good arsenal of weaponry(i believe), I thought the problem was deeper. Had it been one notepad appearing then the solutions given i'm guessing would have worked but one still remains. Again not currently at that PC so cannot make further comment

Comment: @Simon - When you delete files like desktop.ini you can't call unexpected behavior a bug.  All I know is a notepad being opened and having text contained within it, is the same behavior that I saw on a virtual machine, and turned out it was infected with malware ( the infection happened on accident ).

Comment: @Ramhound - i'm not disagreeing with you, I was too quick to respond. The bug so I was told was a recognised "flaw" in the Windows OS in pre-Windows 7 versions causing notepad to autolauch which was obviously still prevalent in Windows 7. The difference being in my case I had two originally, one disappeared due to the solution as outlined below, one still remains (which well be virus initiated as you initially commented)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an old problem from Windows XP which also occurs in some Windows 7 versions. A step-by-step solution is here:
[how-to-fix-notepad-opens-randomly-by-itself-on-windows-7](http://www.webtlk.com/2011/03/08/how-to-fix-notepad-opens-randomly-by-itself-on-windows-7/)

1. Click Start.
2. Click Computer.
3. Click Organize located on the left side of your Windows 7 upper
   toolbar.
4. Click Folder and Search Option.
5. Click the View tab.
6. Under Hidden Folders and Files, click the  Show folders, files and
   drives radio button.
7. Click OK and exit.
8. Now, click Start.
9. In the Search field, type desktop.ini and press Enter.
10. Alternatively, you can also go to:  C: - Program Data - Microsoft
     -Windows -Start Menu -Programs – Startup folder.
11. Right-click it and delete it.
12. Now go to: Go to C: - Users – Your_Username - AppData – Roaming –
     Microsoft – Windows - Start Menu – Startup folder.
13. Again, delete the desktop.ini file.
14. Done! This should stop your notepad from opening by itself!

Comment: You just beat me to it - I copied my answer into yours - please don't just link though, always copy the content as links stop working  :)

Comment: @Dave Rook- Dave thats right desktop.ini file, when I did delete that 12 months ago. It only stopped 1 Notepad from launching (I had 2 appearing on the desktop), 1 still remains. I have to go out now so I cant test anything - be back in about 8 hrs

Comment: @Lee Taylor -  I did the above 12 months ago, the destop.ini file is the attribute that had become unhidden. I think this solution would have worked if there had been only one notepad appearing. It did indeed remove, however one notepad still is autolaunching at startup. From what I recall I went to look for that desktop.ini file on a number of occasions (at the time 12 months ago) and it has been deleted. I am currently away from home computer and cannot check at this present time. So when I am able to check I will.  The "problem" is deeper than that. When I can check that folder later I will

Comment: @Simon - your comment is aimed at Lee Taylor - please note, Lee only edited the post, it was originally created by Paul and as such you probably want to use the @ with Paul's name  :)

Comment: @Lee Taylor - My apologies. I'm new to this. Its an amazing forum. Thx

Comment: @Paul - Please see comments above that were misdirected, my apologies

Comment: @Simon No problem

Comment: @Paul- I have gone through steps outlined above however when I get to Step 12 there isnt a startup folder located within the Start Menu - I know I deleted it in Step 11 !

Comment: @Paul - I just rebooted the computer, and now the second notepad has disappeared. Thankyou very very much (although it is quite bizarre considering I followed those steps around a year ago). I'm also very glad I found this forum and reasked the question....Excellent

Answer (score 1):

Although Pauls' answer may solve this, when programs (this is broader than just notepad) load up at start up you can also look at:

**MSCONFIG**

Open run command and type msconfig - in the start up tab make sure it is not selected (nor any unusual programs which could be causing this).

**Scheduled tasks**

Open task scheduler from the control panel and look through each task to see if any are to launch on start up.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Dave, I know about startup items relating to MSCONFIG, I have a program called Soluto which monitors these. Again will check when I get home :)

Comment: I have checked the startup items in MSCONFIG, thee is no reference to notepad there. I have also checked the task scheduler and there is also no reference to notepad there either. I have gone through the steps outlined below however at step 12 there isnt a start up folder to delete within the start menu

Answer (score 0):

Press `Control + Shift + esc` to open task manager then there go to `start up tab` next to `App History` then from there you'll find out the pages and events that are occurring on boot hence you can delete if a file named `desktop.ini` is found there by right clicking and opening the file location.

Answer (score 0):

notepad starts  when windows start simple fix I had it happen to me all I did was windows update after I was up to date with updates it stopped happening and it was going on for months

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please consider adding more details to your answer, currently it's hard to read and of little value.