# Desktop Widget Fails to AutoStart When I Boot Up my Windows 7 PC?

Tags: windows-7, boot, desktop-gadget

I have a Desktop Widget called Horloger (third party not official Microsoft) (I believe the term Widget is no longer used, and they are now called Gadgets) which would autostart on booting up my PC, and display itself on the desktop. However on the few previous occasions thats I have started my computer it has failed to show.

Instead a dialogue box is produced which says

An unexpected error occurred while reading
(C:\Users\Simon\AppData\Roaming\Amine_Dries\Horloger\Settings.cnf)

I press OK, and another dialogue box appears saying

The process cannot access the file
C:\Users\Simon\AppData\Roaming\Amine_Dries\Horloger\Settings.cnf

because it is being used by another process

and then I press OK.

I might be wrong but I have a feeling it might be related to a problem which has now be solved where notepad would autostart on bootup ie the steps for fixing that somehow caused this "problem" perhaps.
See earlier post [Notepad Automatically Launches Upon Boot Up of my Windows 7 64-Bit Desktop PC](https://superuser.com/questions/511225/notepad-automatically-launches-upon-boot-up-of-my-windows-7-64-bit-desktop-pc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution I think to my problem and that I have just carried out is:

**Uninstall & Reinstall**

This has now solved the issue.

This may well be a generic solution to many computer problems !!

Perhaps someone would care to comment

Comment: What's there to comment? Who knows why or how the app's Settings file might have got corrupted in your case? Obviously a reinstall fixed it by replacing the broken file with a good copy.

Comment: @Karan: I just mean generally speaking thats all, is to uninstall and reinstall the best policy in cases where something doesnt work as its supposed to

Comment: Well it's just common-sense really - if you simply cannot figure it out and fix a broken app/OS, all you can do as a last resort is do a fresh install.

Comment: Thts what I was trying to imply :)